# Can you limit the average function in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with column A having a 0 or a 1, and column B having a value that I want to average. I know I can use averageif(A:A, "=1", B:B) to get the average of all of the values that have a 1 in column A, but I want something a bit more refined.

I want to be able to limit my average to the first ten 1's that show up  in A.

Is this possible? I'd assume so, and that my problem is I just can't find the words to articulate what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a google spreadsheet, something like this should work:

```
=average(array_constrain(filter(B:B, A:A=1),10,1))
```

or alternatively:

```
=average(query(A:B, "Select B where A =1 limit 10",0))
```

Comment: I really like the query style. This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome, Dr. Cyanide. Query is indeed a very powerful function.